# Is it possible to tell whether I am connecting to fast or gigabit ethernet with CAT5e cable?

Tags: ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, cat5e

My NIC supports gigabit ethernet:

```
$ ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: external
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: d
        Link detected: yes
```

My question in other words: I don't know the LAN I am connected to is whether a fast or gigabit ethernet. It could very well be gigabit ethernet and all that time I would have been using only 100 mbps instead of 1 gbps. But since I am connected to LAN with a CAT5e cable (I don't possess a CAT6 cable), is there any way to tell?

Comment: `Speed: 100Mb/s`.  Does that not answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read output?
     `Speed: 100Mb/s`
Looks like 100Mb full duplex to me. But I'm not 100% you title is a well worded question.

Comment: Yes. I edited the question.